# "Please run the JVM with -XStartOnFirstThread" lwjgl IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lwjgl

I'm setting up LWJGL with IntelliJ - everything worked fine until I had to compile the template code. I have this error:

GLFW may only be used on the main thread and that thread must be the first thread in the process. Please run the JVM with -XstartOnFirstThread. This check may be disabled with Configuration.GLFW_CHECK_THREAD0.

I went to the edit configurations menu and did this:

[What I changed it to:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i0wq.png)

This changed nothing and I'm getting the exact same error. Can someone help please?

Comment: It seems that VM option was added to `Program Arguments` field. Make you you add it to the `VM Options` one. https://prnt.sc/EsUTBya7hXLa

Comment: You can post an answer instead of setting title as "solved"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See LWJGL "API docs" for static configuration class.
[org.lwjgl.system.Configuration<T>](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/index.html?org/lwjgl/system/Configuration.html)

**static Configuration<java.lang.Boolean>   GLFW_CHECK_THREAD0**

use a java.util.Properties properties file for command-line arguments and flags to the JVM , you only need to [reference the properties file on the basic startup command line](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/AGOHP/ch05s02s01.html).

The problem appears to be with Mac OS requiring a special restart of the JVM because the thread may not be the first JVM thread (process) the main method is executing the code on, so it requires restart with -XstartOnFirstThread

I'm not actually familiar (vague similarity to starting my apps with a .exe i compiled) but [github has a standard restart .java program to model from](https://github.com/crykn/guacamole/blob/master/gdx-desktop/src/main/java/de/damios/guacamole/gdx/StartOnFirstThreadHelper.java) for that situation.
[Another of that type of process](https://jvm-gaming.org/t/starting-jvm-on-mac-with-xstartonfirstthread-programmatically/57547).